# Joining and emitting to rooms with Socket IO in NestJs

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I am trying to make a simple room in nestjs with socketio and cant grasp the concept of a room. What i want are clients to send an id to a general endpoint and then the server will join that socket to a specific room and then start emitting messages to that room from else where. What I currently have is clients joining to an event called 'meeting' and then being sent a fake meeting but i cannot figure out how to get multiple clients to join the same room and be sent the same information all at once.

Client (html)

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.1/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    const url = 'http://localhost:4001';
    const socket = io(url); 
      socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Connected');
        socket.emit('meeting', { roomId: '12345' });
      });
      socket.on('meeting', function(data) {
        console.log('you have joined the meeting: ', data);
      });
      socket.on('exception', function(data) {
        console.log('event', data);
      });
      socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('Disconnected');
      });
  </script>
```

Server (NestJS):

```
@WebSocketGateway(4001)
export class PackGateway implements OnGatewayConnection {

  constructor(private otherService: OtherService) {}

  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  handleConnection() {
    console.log('new connection!');
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('meeting')
  joinUserToMeeting(@MessageBody() data: any, @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket): Observable<WsResponse<any>> {
    client.join(data.roomId, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error ', err);
      } else {
        console.log('client joined room: ' + data.roomId);
        this.server.to(data.meetingId).emit('a new challenger approaches');
      }
    });
    return from(data.meetingId)
    .pipe(
      map(
        (res: any) => {
          return {
            event: 'meeting',
            data: data.meetingId
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

with this setup my clients are connecting to the meeting event, being joined to the roomId they send when they connect to the meeting event, and being sent back the meetingId they have joined. However I am missing a key thing:

1. Client has not actually opened a connection the room that the server joined it to. Do i need to do this in the client code in order to start a connection to the specific room id? Once I can get something like the below to work then i think my client will get a message when any client joins after it since the server emits a message to that room when a new connection is made.

```
    <script>
    const url = 'http://localhost:4001';
    const socket = io(url);
    socket.on('connect', function () {
      console.log('Connected');
      socket.emit('meeting', { meetingId: '12345' });
    });
    socket.on('meeting', function (data) {
      console.log('you have joined the meeting: ', data);
      socket.in(data).on('roomIdEvent', function (data) {
        console.log('you got a new event specific to the meeting you joined');
        console.log('data');
      });
    });
    socket.on('exception', function (data) {
      console.log('event', data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('Disconnected');
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

realized that when my server emits to that room i was not constructing the message correctly:

so

```
this.server.to(data.meetingId).emit('a new challenger approaches');
```

goes to

```
this.server.to(data.meetingId).emit('meeting', 'a new challenger approaches');
```

and now because my server has joined the clients to that room, sending through the room to meeting allows my clients to see the data